# Character recognition

Tags: matlab, image-processing, ocr

I am new to matlab and I am trying learn OCR in it. For now I am just trying to get a system working before diving into the theory for constructing my own system.

Anyways I am following code snippet from [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8612-character-recognition-example-iii-pre-processing-of-image/content/char2.m)

However whenever I try the code not only my rectangles appear inverted but they also aren't imposed on my original image.

I am thinking that the problem might be here

```
[Ilabel num] = bwlabel(Ifill);
disp(num);
Iprops = regionprops(Ilabel);
Ibox = [Iprops.BoundingBox];
Ibox = reshape(Ibox,[4 50]);
imshow(I)
```

I am using Matlab R2012b. Any help in this regard would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A few references to check:

- [the mathworks docs on character recognition](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/index?utf8=%E2%9C%93&term=character+recognition)
- [Google results on "matlab character recognition"](https://www.google.com/search?q=matlab%20character%20recognition&aq=f&oq=matlab%20character%20recognition&aqs=chrome.0.57.5471&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)
- [Google results on "matlab character recognition"](https://www.google.com/search?q=matlat+character+recognition&aq=f&oq=matlab+character+recognition&aqs=chrome.0.57.5471&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=lv&gs_rn=5&gs_ri=psy-ab&tok=u0Y57ktFY4QZo8b-fH4RaA&pq=matlab%20character%20recognition&cp=23&gs_id=f&xhr=t&q=character+recognition+algorithm&es_nrs=true&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&oq=character+recognition+a&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43148975,d.bGE&fp=b8743810bba186dd&biw=1553&bih=963)

These should be enough to help you successfully finish. I had a similar task and used these. (I had to recognise coins in image with matlab using different algorithms.) So: check all available examples, check all/main existing algorithm examples/ideas (in other languages possibly: the google.lv results were great for me!), then combine them all to better create a working example.

Another good resource if you get stuck: post your question [here, on the mathworks matlab central newsgroup](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/). But be advised: you must have done "your homework" before posting, because people there can help, but (like here) they will not solve the problem for you.

Good luck.